# How to Delete All the Files in the Current Directory Except the Last Two

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, files, rm

Let's say there are 10 files in this current directory `/home/usr`.
They are numbered `1`-`10`. If I wanted to delete all the files except `9` and `10`, how would I go about it?

I can select the bottom two files by doing

```
ls -l /home/usr/ | tail -2
```

However, how would I use this information to remove all BUT the last two? In other words, how would I remove `1`-`8`?

I am going to clarify some things. I would like to remove based on the listing of `ls -l` and not specifically by the name of the files. As in those `1`-`10` files were examples. It should remove files regardless of the specific names and remove the bottom two of `ls -l`.

Comment: "_I would like to remove based on the listing of `ls -l` and not specifically by the name of the files_" Given that `ls -l` produces sorted output what do you perceive as the difference?

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
echo rm -f /home/usr/*(n[1,-3])
```

(remove `echo` when happy)

- `n` to sort in numerical order (10 after 2)
- `[1,-3]` to select only from the first to the third last.

(add the `D` glob qualifier if you also want to consider hidden files)

Comment: I tried this but it returned a syntax error:
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
I'm not too familiar with zsh. Would this be possible in .bash?

Comment: Actually I didn't understand what you meant at first. I realized how it needs to be formatted now. This makes sense. Thanks!


To be specific, it was like this for me:
     echo rm -f /home/usr/[10, 9]

Comment: Wait... Sorry for all the confusion but wouldn't this essentially be "echo rm -f /home/usr/*9? and 10? How would I go about removing based on the bottom two on the list instead of specifically indicating the names on the files

Answer (score 0):

Less beautiful non-`zsh` solution:

```
find . -name 'prefix*' | sort -V | head -n -2 | xargs echo rm --
```

Assuming:

1. Assuming the files all share the same filename prefix `prefix` and have no newlines or other funny characters in their names.
2. Your `sort` supports `-V` and it sorts correctly in your case (I tested it with files in the same simple `prefix` + number form and it works for me, generated using `touch prefix{1..100}` in `bash` BTW).
3. Your `head` supports `-n`.

(The parameters should be supported on all current GNU/Linux distributions.)

Remove `echo` to unlock.

Answer (score 0):

If your files are indeed named 1 to 10, you can use

```
rm {1,8}
```

Or a variation of this to indicate the range, such as `foobar{1,8}`.